# How to know the value of automatic substitutions by sympy after derivation of expression?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm using `sympy` in order to derivate symbolically a complicate expression with `sums,logs,exp`...

I managed to do it (see picture attached and code below) but I have new unknowns `c1,c2 and c3` in the output result.

**I didn't define them by myself. I guess Sympy automatically did it**

My question is, **is there way to print the expression hidden in these c1,c2 and c3 automatically defined by Sympy** ?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> i,b,e,N,B,E = symbols("i b e N B E", cls=Idx)
>>> z =IndexedBase('z')
>>> x =IndexedBase('x')
>>> y =IndexedBase('y')
>>> s2 = Sum((log(Sum(exp(z[b+1,e]*(1/(1+exp(-y[b+1,e])))),[e,1,E])))-(log(Sum(exp(z[b,e]*(1/(1+exp(-y[b,e])))),[e,1,E]))),[b,1,B-1])
>>> print(diff(s2,y[1,1]).doit())
```

Output result: [function and partial derivate with sympy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anznx.png)

Comment: I think you found a bug. SymPy thinks it solved the sum but in reality it hasn't. I don't think this possible to get explicitly since we have no knowledge of the elements of `y` or `z` (Try to solve the third inner sum on the first print statement and you'll see what I mean). This is a bug and for anyone that wants to fix this, the issue occurs [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/concrete/summations.py#L1181-L1187). When `e_exp` is None, `e` does not contain `c2` or `c3` even though the later code thinks that it does.